# `CTTypesetterSuggestLineBreakWithOffset` what is `offset` in this context?

Tags: core-text

I can't understand what this variable `offset` does. I can't see any change if I set random arbitrary values. So what does it do?

Documentation says

```
@function   CTTypesetterSuggestLineBreakWithOffset
@abstract   Suggests a contextual line break point based on the width
            provided.

@discussion The line break can be triggered either by a hard break character
            in the stream or by filling the specified width with characters.

    ... 

@param      offset
            The line position offset.

@result     The value returned is a count of the characters from startIndex
            that would cause the line break. This value returned can be used
            to construct a character range for CTTypesetterCreateLine.


CFIndex CTTypesetterSuggestLineBreakWithOffset(
    CTTypesetterRef typesetter,
    CFIndex startIndex,
    double width,
    double offset ) CT_AVAILABLE(10_6, 3_2);
```